# Discord-Bot can change username, bot not admin-name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was working on my bot and added a funny name generator.
The name-change works, but not for admins.

```
if (message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES") && message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).hasPermission("CHANGE_NICKNAME")) {

      message.guild.member(userID).setNickname('myNicknameGoesHere');
  } else {
      message.channel.send("I dont have the permissons to change my nickname in this server.");
  }
```

When an admin uses the command, I see in the log:

```
(node:20632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Privilege is too low...
```

Comment: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/462

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is a problem with your code, you may need to change a few things in terms of your role management:

`DiscordAPIError: Privilege is too low...`

Your bot needs to have a role higher than the person its trying to nickname I believe it also needs admin permissions to change an admins nickname.

Good luck

Comment: I gave my bot admin permissions, but still not working :|

Comment: @Xanar Sorry, to hear that. Does you're bot have the permissions to change nicknames as well as admin? this may sound dumb, but you're asking if it has permissions to Manage nicknames and change them and it might only have admin, I realise admin gives all permissions but it doesn't tick the box in role management, so if you haven't go tick those boxes. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your Bot must have a higher Role than the user you want to change his Nickname and you cant change the Nick of the Owner. Never.